# Replacing HTML tags does not make a change in the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to remove the html tags from my dataframe object column but it is not working.

```
df.site.replace(to_replace=['<a href="', '</a>'],value='',inplace=True )

Out df.site:
0    <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...
1    <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...
2    <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...
3    <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...
4    <a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" r...
```

When I run it, nothing changes. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"site":['<a href="http://example.com"</a> this is not ']})

df.site = df.site.str.replace(pat=r'(<a href=")|("</a>)',repl = "")

df.site
http://example.com this is not
```